# What is this ball-joint brackets purpose

Tags: mazda, ball-joint

I have a Mazda CX-9/280k which needed passenger lower control arm ball joint replaced. The job went fine, however after completion, I was packing up the tools and had the dreaded moment when you find there is something I had forgotten on the cart.

In this case it was a little stainless steel washer (?) which goes between the hub and the ball-joint:

[image]

What is the purpose of this part? Do I need to revisit the job, to reinsert it? Currently the install looks like:

[image]

Update: Below is the other size. It just slides over the top of the ball-joint:

[image]

Comment: Where *exactly* does this part fit? Can you show us a pic of where it's installed on the other side of the vehicle?

Comment: Added the pick, just seems to clip over the hub

Comment: What year is it? Looks like a scuff shield for the ball joint rubber.

Comment: Year is 2008... scuff shield, that could make sense. I guess i could accomplish the same if i keep it lubed with silicon grease

Comment: Agree with this, probably to prevent the boot from sticking and twisting during sharp turns, probably increases the service life of the boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.. It looks like its made from stainless steel so I also would think its to prevent the ball joint boot from sticking to the hub assy and possibly wearing/tearing it.